# How do I create game macros/automated shortcuts for Minecraft on Mac OS X?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, macos

I want to create some macros for a server on Minecraft. One example would be /home. The server doesn't allow two of the same strings in  a row to be sent, so if the last command I used was /home and I wanted to use it again, I'd usually do this:

1. Press <kbd>/</kbd> (which opens the console and prefills a /)
2. Press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to send it
3. Press <kbd>/</kbd> again
4. Type "home"
5. Press <kbd>Enter</kbd> again to send the command

I'd like to make a macro that did all when I pressed <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd>, but only if I was in Minecraft (and if possible, only on that particular server).

Comment: This question is not actually gaming-specific; one could replace the word "minecraft" with any application and get an equaly valid question. Thus, I'm flagging this for closure as off-topic.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it only uses a game as an example for an otherwise general question.

Answer (score 2):

1. Install and open [Keyboard Maestro](http://www.keyboardmaestro.com/main/)
2. Create a new macro (+ button at the bottom of the Macros collum)
3. Call it what you like
4. Click 'New Trigger' (next to green +), then select 'Hot Key Trigger'
5. Press <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd>
6. Click 'New Action', then select the 'Control Flow' category
7. Double-click 'If Then Else' to add it
8. Within the new action added to the macro, click 'New Condition', then select 'Application Condition'
9. Select Minecraft (the one with the console icon, not the one with the Minecraft icon, you may have to select 'More...' or 'Other...')
10. Click inside the first 'No Action'
11. Select the 'Text' category on the left, then add 'Type a Keystroke'
12. Click where it says 'Return' and change it to '/' by pressing <kbd>/</kbd>
13. Select the 'Control Flow' category on the left, add 'Pause', and change it to .1 seconds (it doesn't seem to work without these delays, I used .1 just to make it as short as possible)
14. Add another 'Type a Keystroke' action (step 10), don't change 'Return' (you can also use <kbd>⌘</kbd> + D to duplicate actions)
15. Add another 'Pause' action
16. Add another / Keystroke and Pause (steps 11-12)
17. Select the 'Text' category again, add 'Insert Text by Typing', and type "home"
18. Add another Return Keystroke

Your macro should look like this when you're done: [image: finished macro]